# ezpublish 4.3.0. management screen

Tags: php, ezpublish

I am using ezpublish 4.3.0. The management screen is collapsed when repeating generation / editing of class etc. from the management screen, it is in a state where you can not put it in. Please tell me how to respond and the tpl file (file with the extension tpl) that creates the administration screen. This environment has been customized when it was first constructed, and presumably that tpl going to see css etc in this treatment changed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, i'm not sure i completely understand what you need but the template files for the administration area are all under `/design/admin` if someone made an extension to override the admin template try and disable it from administration siteaccess under `/settings/siteaccess/$yourSiteAccessName`.

By the way you could try and clear the cache, sometime it fixes some of those issues, you never know